# Upgrade PHP 5.1.6 to 5.2 Issues

Tags: php, apache-2.2, centos

I am trying to upgrade PHP 5.1.6 to 5.2. I am using:

```
yum update
```

However, when I restart apache and run `phpinfo();` or `rpm -qa |grep php` is still has version 5.1.6.

I am running Apcache2(CentOS 5.5).

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: @prodigitalson - There are quite a few other questions here about upgrading PHP so I thought this would be OK.

Comment: So in essence `rpm -qa` says that you still have 5.1.6 installed? Then restarting Apache will have no effect. Download a real PHP 5.2 package, and install it by hand instead of using yum.

Comment: Its not that it isnt ok per se. But since its not an issue with compiling/building errors or something like that, IMO its more related to the repository configuration of your install which is more appropriately placed on ServerFault.

Comment: @mario. Thank you for your response. I was wary of doing this as I have read it can mess with your current setup. Would i just manually download using 'wget http://uk.php.net/distributions/php-5.2.17.tar.bz2' and then unpack and ./configure etc?

Comment: @mario: personally i would consider that a last resort. Cent is just more conservative about its mainline packages so there is probably another `stable` package source he needs to add that is less conservative or from a respected third party.

Comment: @Christopher: Well you could do that. It's just a bit more boring. But certainly there are third-party RPM repositories where you can find a pre-packaged php5.2 installable via rpm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have to specify a newer package source.

Comment: @PMV. Right OK. Something like 'wget http://uk.php.net/distributions/php-5.2.17.tar.bz2r' and then unpack and install?

Comment: I'm more familiar with apt-get, but if you point to a 3rd party repo, you should be able use yum (update, install).  Take a look here: http://www.jasonlitka.com/yum-repository/  I think there's a 5.2 source on his site.